# change some color to transparent in UIImage

Tags: ios, swift

i have color 255.0.180 and i need to convert this color to transparent. When i use white color, this code works fine:

```
     image = UIImage(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)!)!

    let rawImageRef: CGImageRef = image.CGImage!

    let colorMasking: [CGFloat] = [222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255]
    //        222.0/255.0, 255.0/255.0,
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    let maskedImageRef=CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(rawImageRef, colorMasking);


    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, image.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, -1.0);


    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), maskedImageRef);
    let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return  result!
```

when i use same code with colorMasking: 222, 255, 222, 0, 255, 180 - doesn't work.
Can you help me, please?

Comment: sry, i don't know what you mean? Iam new in this problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you want you could just call this UIColor.clearColor() this gives you a transparant color.